# Top Down Shooter Player Movement Control in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Background: Making a small game in Unity 3D. It is a top down shooter. I am moving the player by using the MovePosition() function on its rigidbody with isKinematic set to false and not using gravity.

Desired behavior: When the player collides with a obstacle in the scene I want the script that controls the player to stop trying to force it into the object.

Problem: The rigidbody and colliders of the game objects successfully prevent the player from moving through solid objects but the player jitters sometimes and if the object is small enough the player glitches over the object even though the Y-position of the player is locked.

Question: What is the best way to do player movement for a Top Down Shooter? Should I use a NavMesh? rigidBody?

Comment: `if(wouldCollide(postion + moveoffset)) { doNothing(); } else { move(); }`

Comment: I found something called sweep test that can check if something is going to collide.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTest.html

Im going to try implementing the pseudo code that you wrote above and see if it works.

Comment: There is also [`Physics.Sphere/Capsule/Box Cast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I used for my Top-Down shooter, I hope this helps :)

Code -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public float bulletForce = 20f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.AddForce(firePoint.up * bulletForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was that the answer you were looking for? If so please can you approve it!